# Redirect my domain.com to facebook canvas page

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-apps

I have an app on http://apps.facebook.com/myappname that is a canvas page of http://mydomain.com.

I dont want the user to access mydomain.com, so i want to redirect him to http://apps.facebook.com/myappname.

Whats the best wat to do this? I was trying to redirect via javascript,php and htaccess but i get an error since facebook uses my url do load the canvas page. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: See this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076359/force-facebook-app-to-use-page-tab-iframe

Comment: The problem is that FB.Canvas.getPageInfo only works inside apps.facebook.com/appname. I cant use it when outside. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
function referrerIsFacebookApp() {
    if(document.referrer) {
        return document.referrer.indexOf("facebook.com") !== -1;
    }
    return false;
}
if (!referrerIsFacebookApp()) {
    top.location.replace("http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME_SPACE");
}
```

PHP:

```
function referrerIsFacebookApp() {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "facebook.com") === false || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "facebook.com/l.php?u=") !== false) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
if (!referrerIsFacebookApp()) {
    header("Location: http://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME_SPACE");
}
```

Comment: Nice! I've used the same logic with a php variable: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: Hola Pedro, I've updated my answere with a PHP equivalent of the JavaScript code above. Guess you've done it in a similar way.

Comment: Do you have any solution to redirect with the respectives parameters of the url?

Comment: You should be able to get the parameters with `$params = array();
if (count($_GET) > 0) { $params = $_GET; } else { $params = $_POST; }` and append them to your redirect url.

Comment: I'll use the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to redirect to the same path. What about ajax calls? Will them be redirected too? I didnt test it yet, but i'll use ajax very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the signed_request parameter transfers when loading your app in its iframe.

Comment: But the signed_request there is no data about it. Take a look of my signed request: 

array (size=6)
  'algorithm' => string 'HMAC-SHA256' (length=11)
  'expires' => int 1340391600
  'issued_at' => int 1340385170
  'oauth_token' => string 'XXXX' (length=113)
  'user' => 
    array (size=3)
      'country' => string 'br' (length=2)
      'locale' => string 'pt_BR' (length=5)
      'age' => 
        array (size=1)
          'min' => int 21
  'user_id' => string 'XXXX' (length=9)